# Formatting the output of ComponentMeasurements

Tags: image-processing

I have some code written here which uses ComponentMeasurements to output some data, specifically the one below:

```
dnaList = ComponentMeasurements[dnaFragsL, "Length"]
Histogram[dnaList]
```

The first line of code generates the output

```
{1 -> 177.7, 2 -> 80.4449, 3 -> 338.173, 4 -> 270.588, 5 -> 379.699, 
 6 -> 93.3377, 7 -> 69.6693, 8 -> 214.073, 9 -> 370.709, 10 -> 81.386,
  11 -> 160.486, 12 -> 90.3487, 13 -> 208.946, 14 -> 138.308, 
 15 -> 86.0753, 16 -> 65.237, 17 -> 65.2137, 18 -> 106.573, 
 19 -> 141.393, 20 -> 129.238, 21 -> 79.7561, 22 -> 60.7805, 
 23 -> 73.7609, 24 -> 86.4439, 25 -> 101.005, 26 -> 120.764, 
 27 -> 229.084, 28 -> 131.506, 29 -> 98.6205, 30 -> 26.1816, 
 31 -> 387.531, 32 -> 179.419, 33 -> 62.0383, 34 -> 60.3329}
```

which does not appear to be an array or list and cannot be fed into the Histogram function. What transform has to be carried out in order for it to generate usefully formatted output?

The image dnaFragsL is attached below.

[image: test image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to transform the measures returned by `ComponentMeasurements` you can do the following `Rule` replacement:

```
 lengths = dnaList  /. Rule[a_, b_] -> b
```

> ```
> {177.7, 80.4449, 338.173, 270.588, 379.699, 93.3377, 69.6693,
> 214.073, 370.709, 81.386, 160.486, 90.3487, 208.946, 138.308,
> 86.0753, 65.237, 65.2137, 106.573, 141.393, 129.238, 79.7561, 
> 60.7805, 73.7609, 86.4439, 101.005, 120.764, 229.084, 131.506, 
> 98.6205, 26.1816, 387.531, 179.419, 62.0383, 60.3329}
> ```

The function i used here as a shortcut (`/.`) is called `ReplaceAll`. Passing the resulting list `lengths` to `Histogram` gives you:

```
Histogram[lengths]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can extract the lengths:

```
Histogram[#[[2]] & /@ dnaList]
```

[image]

Apologies, if I have misinterpreted your question.

Comment: Better performance can be had with `dnaList[[All, 2]]`; greater readability may be had with `Last /@ dnaList` (+1 for first answer nevertheless)

Comment: Points taken, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In version 9 you can use the *Suggestion Bar* to do this for you:

[image: suggestion bar]

The action you're looking for is "*apply rules to variables*".